# Functioning wordpress site address moved on same domain and server per WP directions but not now showing up

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Co-Hosting on GoDaddy, have had a fully functioning WordPress site setup under the primary domain in a sub-folder renamed from "/wordpress/" to "/opportunities/" as in => "http: //howtoliveoffthegridnow.com]/opportunities/" Naturally, this works perfectly just as it should!

Following the WP directions for moving the "Site Address(URL) while leaving the "WordPress Address(URL) as above, I "copied" the ".htaccess" and "index.php" files from the "WordPress Address(URL) "/opportunities/" folder, as above, into the newly designated folder "shopping" so that the "Site Address(URL)" now becomes "http: //shopping.howtoliveoffthegridnow.com/" This works as it should and equally as well as the original setup above!

In the case of the folder housing the principle php based web content (not WP content) labeled "howtoliveoffthegridnow.com", this is located under our version of GoDaddy "public_html" home folder. our "/opportunities/" folder is a sub-folder located under "howtoliveoffthegridnow.com". Our new "shopping" folder is directly under the GoDaddy "public_html" home folder. The site DNS record has been updated to include an "A" hosting record for this "shopping" subdomain name.

The content of the ".htaccess" file now copied into the "Shopping" folder, per WP directions, is as follows:

```
    `# BEGIN WordPress`
    `# From wordpress itself after changing site address`
    `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`
    `RewriteEngine On`
    `RewriteBase /`
    `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
    `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]'
    `</IfModule>'
    `# END WordPress`
```

The content of the "index.php" file now copied into the "Shopping" folder, per WP directions, is as follows:

```
`<?php'
`/**'
` * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do`
`   anything, but loads
` * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.`
` *`
` * @package WordPress`
` */`
`/**`
` * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.`
` *`
` * @var bool'
` */`
` // remove 'shopping' subdomain name from directory path`
`$dir_root = str_ireplace('/shopping', '', dirname(__FILE__)); `
`/wp-blog-header.php'." <br />";`
`define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);`

`/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */'
`//require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/howtoliveoffthegridnow.com/opportunities/wp-blog-header.php' );'
`require( $dir_root . '/howtoliveoffthegridnow.com/opportunities/wp-blog-header.php' );'
```

With these two files set in the "shopping" folder, the content of the original WordPress installation in "http: //howtoliveoffthegridnow.com/opportunities/" shows up perfectly under "http: //shopping.howtoliveoffthegridnow.com/" This also works perfectly just as it should.

However, when subsequently changing the sub-domain of the "Site Address(URL)" from "shopping" to "deals" with this new address by creating a new folder with the name "deals" under the same overall site public_html home folder off the same domain and server setup as described above for "shopping" and respectively for "/opportunities/" all per WP directions, copying the required ".htaccess" and "index.php" files into "deals", now when choosing "http: //deals.howtoliveoffthegridnow.com/" instead of "http: //shopping.howtoliveoffthegridnow.com/", the "deals" site shows only a page with nothing but the default "Coming Soon" motif/blank page instead of the WordPress content which shows up perfectly under either "shopping" or "/opportunities/" respectively when the "Site Address(URL)" data is accordingly respectively changed to suit the desired output URL.

The site DNS record has also been updated to include an "A" hosting record for this "deals" subdomain name.

Note also: The "index.php" file for the "deals" folder was edited to change:

```
` // remove 'shopping' subdomain name from directory path`
`$dir_root = str_ireplace('/shopping', '', dirname(__FILE__)); `
```

to:

```
` // remove 'deals' subdomain name from directory path`
`$dir_root = str_ireplace('/deals', '', dirname(__FILE__)); `
```

Any suggestions as to what is wrung :) here would be most gratefully received.

Note: gaps left between each "http:" and the "//.??restoftheurl.com" in the above are there simply to comply with the limit imposed restricting the number of links that can be included in a post and should be ignored if you choose to try following any of those links.

Answer (score 0):

Insomuch as I could gather from your question, you are trying to move (migrate) the WordPress site from a sub-folder to a subdomain (and it is not working).

Here is how I would go about with this:

On your original/working (sub-folder based) site, install this plug-in:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Next, generate a Duplicator package (via the plug-in's menu on wp-admin dashboad).

Once the package is generated, download the two package files (installer.php and the archive/zip file) to your PC. Next, upload these two files to the sub-domain (deals) folder where you wish to create the site. Next, open the following link in your browser:

http://deals.howtoliveoffthegridnow.com/installer.php

and follow on-screen instructions. Your site should get created and everything should work fine.

Comment: That is a great suggestion @Open Source Training Rajkot. While it is not exactly the answer for which I was looking because it is not a migration of the WP install that I have been attempting to accomplish, however this option does open up an alternative way to achieve the desired end goal which is to have WP show up under a different sub-domain from the sub-domain that does work. Thank you for the suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I am embarrassed to admit - but I do admit, that the problem seems have have occurred because apparently I inadvertently skipped over a critical step in creating "deals" as a sub-domain when adding it to my file structure in the GoDaddy cPanel options.

Instead of starting from the cPanel icon for creating a new sub domain, I went straight to the DSN records page and created the new record manually which bypassed the under-the-covers code that would connect the sub-domain folder into the web hierarchy correctly, thus although one could pull up the sub-domain by entering its URL in the browser, that result was effectively orphaned from its related primary domain.

Having retraced my steps and followed through in correctly adding this sub=domain, **the problem has now been resolved**.

The lesson here seems to be that we just cannot skip steps because that defeats us in the effort to reach our goal when the underlying systems are bypassed.